# Data conversion: Assigning 4 byte data from array into 1 byte array

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, generic-programming

First of all, let me explain a little bit about the environment. I am using C for the embedded 32-bit microcontroller. doing unit tests via various tools but results are the same. printf is used only for a test with MinGW.

I am trying to copy data from an array of float32 (4Byte array) (IEEE754) into a byte array.

I am working with only Hex Data only here and it is important that the location of hex value is accurate i.e:

```
If CalibData[0] = 01 02 03 04
```

then Data should look like this:

```
   Data[0] = 01
   Data[1] = 02
   Data[2] = 03
   Data[3] = 04
```

The possibilities which I could think of are similar to a below-mentioned code block:

```
/*CalibData is a Global variable and change by other components, I am only reading it here*/
float32 CalibData [1920];

/*Data is an argument for my function and shall return it with values read from CalibData*/
int Data[7680];

/* Approach 1: */

uint16_t dataElementCounter = 0;
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 1920; i++)
{
Data[dataElementCounter] = (uint8) ((uint32) calib_Data[i] >> 24);
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = (uint8) ((uint32) calib_Data[i] >> 16);
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = (uint8) ((uint32) calib_Data[i] >> 8);
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = (uint8) ((uint32)calib_Data[i]);
dataElementCounter++;
}

/* Approach 2: */
for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 1920; i++)
{
memcpy((uint8*) Data[0], &calib_Data[i],sizeof(float));
}
```

Now the problem is that if i am using Approach 1 then,  it is difficult to test without hardware if the data has been copying correctly because testing it via unit test or printf is always providing truncated data. For instance

```
if CalibData[0] = 1.0;
```

According to IEEE754 it should be 0x3F 0x80 0x00 0x00 in Hex but in unit test or printf it will do it like this:

CalibData >> 24 is a fraction 1.0 / 16777216. When converted to uint32 it truncates to 0.
CalibData >> 16 is a fraction 1.0 / 65536. Likewise.
CalibData >> 8 is a fraction 1.0 / 256. Likewise.
CalibData is 1.0. That will become 1 as a uint32.

so the data will be shown as :

```
Data[0] = 0
Data[1] = 0
Data[2] = 0
Data[3] = 1
```

And if i am using Approach 2 then code is showing garbage values in Data.

Kindly tell me a better way to do it or improvement of one of the above-mentioned approaches.

Regards

Comment: "The embedded 32-bit microcontroller?"  You know there is more than one , right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ist the cast `(uint32)` as it is converting the `float` into a `uint32`, and that is not what you want.

You best bet is this excerpt:

```
union {
    float f;
    uint8 b[4];
} u;

u.f = calib_Data[i];
Data[dataElementCounter] = u.b[0];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = u.b[1];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = u.b[2];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = u.b[3];
dataElementCounter++;
```

Beware, this is not conforming to the C standard. But it might work on your actual system.

**EDIT 1**

Still not conforming, but without usage of `union`, you can emulate this with casted pointers:

```
const uint8* b = (const uint8*)(calib_Data + i); // equally, but simpler to read than &calib_Data[i]
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[0];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[1];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[2];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[3];
dataElementCounter++;
```

This is similar to codetest's answer, which even better suggests to use `memcpy()`:

```
memcpy(Data + dataElementCounter, calib_Data + i, sizeof calib_Data[i]);
dataElementCounter += sizeof calib_Data[i];
```

The last option has two main advantages:

1. It is up-front understandable with as few lines as possible.
2. It is safe against changes in the size of `calib_Data`'s data type.

**EDIT 2**

Requirement: you **must** swap the bytes.

If your target system is fixed, and if you are totally sure what you are doing, the first thing to do is to document this in a comment. Additionally, you might like to check the compiler:

```
 #if !defined(MY_COMPILER_ID)
 #error Compiler not supported
 #endif
```

To store the float in reversed order, you can use the first alternative of EDIT 1 with inverted indexes:

```
const uint8* b = (const uint8*)(calib_Data + i); // equally, but simpler to read than &calib_Data[i]
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[3];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[2];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[1];
dataElementCounter++;
Data[dataElementCounter] = b[0];
dataElementCounter++;
```

To make it future-safe against changes in the size of `calib_Data`'s data type, you'll need a loop:

```
const uint8* b = (const uint8*)(calib_Data + i); // equally, but simpler to read than &calib_Data[i]
int b_i;
for (b_i = sizeof calib_Data[i] - 1; b_i >= 0; --b_i) {
    Data[dataElementCounter] = b[b_i];
    dataElementCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your analysis is correct but unfortunately, I can not use unions in my code due to some conformance limitations

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer, I found your second approach much useful and now i am able to see the correct data in the debugger but it is flipped. for e.g i am expecting
Data[0] = 3F
Data[1] = 80
Data[2] = 00
Data[3] = 00

But i am getting as follow result
 
Data[0] = 00
Data[1] = 00
Data[2] = 80
Data[3] = 3F

Can you suggest something to flip this order ?

Comment: Unfortunately, First approach is not working for me and returning 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 as my own  code but memcpy approach seems to be working fine but only reuslts are flipped. I could not think of a way how to flip the float order with memcpy. However, thanks for the really good explaination and additional info about security. i will definately do that.

Comment: If `memcpy()` seems to work, just flipped, your data type of `Data` is not `int` but `uint8_t` or some else with a size of 1. -- As you found, `memcpy()` can not flip. You have to do this yourself.

Comment: you were right, i flip the bytes myself after memcpy and it works like charm. Thanks alot for your guidance. The problem is now solved.